# Simulating button click in Tcl/TK R package

Tags: r, user-interface, tcl

I would like to simulate a button click to switch from one tab to another after a specific action has been performed. I.e. say there are two tabs, and I am currently located in the second tab. I click a button in the second tab which calls a function that changes the second tab to the first tab. I am not sure how to "mimic" the button click that Tcl/TK handles when switching tabs using the mouse. Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: In general, all relevant events on Tk widgets become one or more calls to the methods of that widget. (The exceptions are redraws and resizes, which are truly automatic.) In MVC terms, Tk uses views in C, models in C (with mapping into your script when set up right), and controllers that are scripted (the class bindings for the most part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab notebooks have a `select` method that does tab selection. Which tab to switch to can be chosen by a few schemes, but the important ones for most code are:

1. By index (counting from zero; 0 for the first tab, 1 for the second, ...)
2. By handle of managed child widget (often a frame, but not necessarily)